# Contacts Issue: Google Contacts, Nokia 5800 And Outlook, Sync and Images

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007, google-contacts, symbian

this is a multi-question, so please, feel free to answer just one or all of them.

My actual situation is: Google contacts sync with Nokia 5800 using MFE(google sync), using google's fake "exchange server".

Outlook sync with google using GoContact Sync software (http://www.webgear.co.nz/Products/GOContactSync.aspx).

What I want, a easy(or not) way to correctly sync the three of them, even if I have to change some of my "escenario". I know outlook<->google contacts sync is not good yet, but if someone can suggest me some better SW than GoContact Sync. It'll be good. What I really want is to sync a least name, phone, email and image.

Then, is there a way to get all my google contacts to by default use their own google image? I noted that, usually i have to manually choose it, and sometimes it doesn't work. I'll like to use something or someone's service to do this automatically.

I have tried some services like Soocial, but it gives me a lot of trouble after the first sync, because soccial can ONLY get ALL your contacts, not just "My Contacts"; and also it gives me like 100 bad contacts in outlook because of their beta client.

The final goal of all of this is to

- Get only "My Contacts" from google in Outlook and in the 5800 with their images
- Get ALL my contacts with their default image, meaning, the contact's personal image
- Get a solution to correctly sync the three of them, using Google's as the base for the rest of them.

Thanks in advance. Again, feel free to sugest me solutions to just one or all them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just recently started using [gSyncit](http://www.daveswebsite.com/software/gsync/) to sync my calendars and contacts from Google to Outlook, and I've had a lot of success with it.

In terms of its contact support, it will pull in all of the data you mentioned (name, phone email and image) and lot more besides. It will also allow you to select contact groups for syncing, rather than all contacts. So I just pull in "My contacts", and ignore the rest.

It isn't free, but at $15 I think it provides good value. On top of that its already compatible with both the 32- and 64-bit flavours of Outlook 2010.

Comment: Very Good App. I'm Buying it now.
Very very nice! Thanks!

Comment: Just for records. I've been using this app for almost 3 days, but 3 intensive-use days. Everything is okay and working pretty good, even I can say, perfectly.
The notes sync is just great!
Also, working just fine with outlook 2007, and again fine when I installed(upgraded) to 2010 beta